# Storing path to filesystem trigger in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using the Filesystem Trigger in Jenkins to monitor a folder for any folders named 'alpha', if one is found, the job gets kicked off. How can I get the full path to the newly found 'alpha' folder in the jenkins pipeline? Is it stored in an environment variable or anything? Thanks.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/fstrigger/

I tried echoing out the local environment variables for the jenkins job that was triggered but I don't see anything listed.